# Question marks inside of upright rectangles after compiling?

Tags: c

I compiled a program that translates infix notation to postfix notation, and afterwards I got these '?' inside of upright rectangles. I'm on a Windows computer and using GNU gcc to compile.

Can anyone explain to me what the question marks are for or why they appeared?

I'll provide the code that I have.

stack.h

```
typedef struct Stack {
    int top;
    int MAXSTACKSIZE;
    int * stk;
} Stack;

void InitializeStack(Stack * stack, int length);
int Precedence(char symbol);
void Push(Stack * stack, int element);
int Pop(Stack * stack);
int Top(Stack * stack);
int Size_S(Stack * stack);
int isEmpty(Stack * stack);
void Convert(Stack * stack, char infix[], char postfix[]);
void PrintStack(Stack * stack);
```

stack.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "stack.h"

void InitializeStack(Stack * stack, int length) {
    stack -> stk = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    stack -> MAXSTACKSIZE = length;
    stack -> top = -1;
}

int Precedence(char symbol) {
    if (symbol == '^') {
        return 3;
    } else if (symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || symbol == '%') {
        return 2;
    } else if (symbol == '+' || symbol == '-') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void Push(Stack * stack, int element) {
    int * temp;
    int i;
    if (Size_S(stack) == stack -> MAXSTACKSIZE) {
        stack -> MAXSTACKSIZE++;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(int) * stack -> MAXSTACKSIZE);
        for (i = 0; i < Size_S(stack); i++) {
            temp[i] = stack -> stk[i];
        }  
        free(stack -> stk);
        stack -> stk = temp;
    }
    int t = stack -> top + 1;
    stack -> top = t;
    stack -> stk[t] = element;
}

int Top(Stack * stack) {
    if (isEmpty(stack)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return stack -> stk[stack -> top];
}

int Pop(Stack * stack) {
    int element;
    if (isEmpty(stack)){
        return -1;
    }
    element = Top(stack);
    stack -> stk[stack -> top] = 0;
    stack -> top = stack -> top - 1;
    return element;
}

int Size_S(Stack * stack) {
    return (stack -> top) + 1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack * stack) {
    if (stack -> top == -1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void Convert(Stack * stack, char infix[], char postfix[]) {
    char x, token;
    int i, j;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; infix[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        token = infix[i];
        if (isalnum(token)) {
            postfix[j++] = token;
        } else if (token == '(') {
            Push(stack, '(');
        } else if (token == ')') {
            while ((x = Pop(stack)) != '(') {
                postfix[j++] = x;
            } 
        } else {
            while (Precedence(token) <= Precedence(Top(stack)) && !isEmpty(stack))
            {
                x = Pop(stack);
                postfix[j++] = x;
            }
            Push(stack, token);
        }
    }
    while (!isEmpty(stack))
    {
        x = Pop(stack);
        postfix[j++] = x;
    }
    postfix[j] = '\0';
}

void PrintStack(Stack * stack) {
    int length = Size_S(stack);
    printf("Length: %d\n", length);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", stack -> stk[i]);
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main() {
    Stack * stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    int i;
    InitializeStack(stack, 1);
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Push(stack,i);
        printf("Size of stack: %d, MaxSize: %d\n", Size_S(stack), stack ->   MAXSTACKSIZE);
    }
    printf("Top element: %d\n", Top(stack));
    PrintStack(stack);
    puts("");
    int popped = Pop(stack);
    printf("Popped: %d\n", popped);
    PrintStack(stack);
    puts("");
    //postfix test
    char infix[30], postfix[30];
    printf("Enter an infix expression(eg: 5+2*4): ");
    gets(infix);
    Convert(stack, infix, postfix);
    printf("\nPostfix expression: %s", postfix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _and afterwards I got these '?'_ Those seem to be missing from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have unwanted code leftovers (most likely previously used for testing).

When entering the `Convert` function the stack already has some (garbage) entries in it. `Convert` does it job and populates `postfix` with the desired data, but at the end the loop `while (!isEmpty(stack))` also adds the unwanted entries, so that a *hex* representation of `postfix` would look like:

> 35 32 34 2A 2B 0A 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

The first 5 hex chars correspond (are the *ASCII* codes) to `524*+` which is the postfixed form (if entering the expression in the example), the next (11 - including the 1<sup>st</sup> *(0x)00* which by coincidence is the string *NULL* terminator - so it doesn't get printed on screen by `printf`) are values pushed into the stack by the unwanted code (*[0..11]* pushed by the `for` loop in main, then 11 being poped - resulting *[0..10]* - of course poped in reversed order). Those are the gibberish symbols that `printf` spits on the screen (until it encounters *0x00*).

Comment the unwanted code in *main.c* like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main() {
    Stack * stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    int i;
    InitializeStack(stack, 1);
    /*
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Push(stack,i);
        printf("Size of stack: %d, MaxSize: %d\n", Size_S(stack), stack ->   MAXSTACKSIZE);
    }
    printf("Top element: %d\n", Top(stack));
    PrintStack(stack);
    puts("");
    int popped = Pop(stack);
    printf("Popped: %d\n", popped);
    PrintStack(stack);
    puts("");
    //*/
    //postfix test
    char infix[30], postfix[30];
    printf("Enter an infix expression(eg: 5+2*4): ");
    gets(infix);
    Convert(stack, infix, postfix);
    printf("\nPostfix expression: %s", postfix);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lol, thank you. I was looking at it like I broke the compiler, when I just needed to either clear the stack before Convert or comment out the stack test.

Comment: You're welcome! Piece of mind: You're never going to break the compiler (if you were to do that (or the person who wrote this code), then your code wouldn't simply compile)